# for(;;){} what does it do?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Simple question: I've been looking over boost's asio library, and keep coming across code like this.

```
for(;;){
//something
}
```

There's an example of this [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1.html).

Can anyone elaborate as to what using ";;" within a for loop does?  I can't seem to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

Its a simple infinite loop syntax, a complete code looks like this

```
for(<initialize>; <condition>; <increment/decrement>) {
   <body>
}
```

Those I labelled with '< .. >' are optional.

Comment: its also the same as saying 'while(true){ }'

Comment: Okay makes sense.  Figured it'd be simple. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yeah an I got a downvote for it. No problem.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you answer a question that has been asked and answered numerous times?

Comment: Technically the last part is not necessary increment/decrement (although most of the time that's what it is). It can be any expression. Didn't downvote you though.

Comment: If it bothers you so much, @Anonymous, why didn't you vote to close the question as a duplicate?